# create a code(python) that reads the reviews from a URL and extracts the author, date, review text and score, saving them in a json document

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, request

For whatever reason the reviews do not appear in my json file and i can't figure out why, the program does not give any errors. It also only reads from the first five pages of a site as to not end up with to many reviews but that is not important, i only made it like that to work faster. I have tried this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = "https://www.yelp.ie/biz/diwali-indian-restaurant-dublin"

reviews = []

num_pages = 5

for page in range(1, num_pages+1):
    
    review_url = url + f"/review/p{page}"

    
    response = requests.get(review_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    
    review_list = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "card-item js-product-data"})

   
    for review in review_list:
        author = review.find("div", {"class": "review-title"}).text.strip()
        date = review.find("div", {"class": "review-date"}).text.strip()
        text = review.find("div", {"class": "review-text js-review-text"}).text.strip()
        score = review.find("div", {"class": "review-stars-text"}).text.strip()

       
        reviews.append({"author": author, "date": date, "text": text, "score": score})


with open("reviews.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump({"reviews": reviews}, outfile, indent=4)
```

Do i have to change anything?

Comment: You'll notice that if you load the page in a browser with JavaScript turned off, none of the reviews appear. This means that they are added by JavaScript after the HTML is loaded. They're not in the HTML you're retrieving, as a simple `print(response.content)` would have revealed instantly. There are ways to work around this but the answer to "Do I have to change anything?" is yes, you need to change the entire approach.

Comment: Then should i give up on BeautifulSoup and try with Selenium instead?

Comment: The approach I'd use is to figure out what URL it's getting the reviews from, and read that. You can find that out by watching the Network tab in the browser console while you load the page.  It's probably in JSON format, which you can parse Python's JSON library, no BeautifulSoup required.

Comment: But if i have to make the code for a random URL?

Comment: I mean, every site is going to be different no matter how you want to scrape it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the reviews are loaded from external URL via JavaScript. To simulate this request you can use  next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.yelp.ie/biz/diwali-indian-restaurant-dublin"
review_url = "https://www.yelp.ie/biz/{biz_id}/review_feed?rl=en&q=&sort_by=relevance_desc&start={start}"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
biz_id = soup.select_one('[name=yelp-biz-id]')['content']

for start in range(0, 20, 10):  # <-- increase this range for loading more reviews
    r_url = review_url.format(biz_id=biz_id, start=start)
    data = requests.get(r_url, headers=headers).json()
    for r in data['reviews']:
        # print some sample data from review:
        print(BeautifulSoup(r['comment']['text'], 'html.parser').text)
        print()
```

Prints:

```
...

I came here on a Friday night with some coworkers. The owner told us it would be a 15 minute wait but we ended up waiting outside for about 45 minutes. It's quite cold in Dublin so I was not pleased at all.The restaurant is also quite small. We were very cramped and basically encroaching on the next table. Oops!The staff is pretty nice. I guess they knew we were waiting for so long so we did get some free food and flaming shots out of the whole experience.I got one of the korma dishes. It was not bad! It was a bit sweeter than I expected (probably because they added rose water?) and it was a bright yellow. I would eat it again though.I probably wouldn't wait over 30 minutes next time though.

Lunch 12.30-3pm offer is a really must have in Dublin. Hands down the best Indian restaurant in Dublin. Lunch offer is only €9.99 for a starter and main which comes with either rice or naan, and also includes coffee and tea. You also get Papadums as appetisers for free. How can you get such a deal in this city now!? All their meats are beautifully well seasoned and so tender. I've never tasted such tender meat in any restaurants before. It is really really good. Very authentic Indian food, especially coming from me who have lived in Asia my entire life! :) Very under rated place since everyone is now crazy over eggs and brunch food stuff. Definitely worth to come during lunch or when they have their offers. Ala cate menu can be really pricey though. The portion size may look small, but trust me it gets really filling! Felt so full! Never felt so satisfied. Must try: ANY MEAT DISH. And their peshwari naan!

...
```

Comment: If i were to use any other URL wouldn't i have to change most things every time?

Comment: @MISHA I believe not. Try to change the `url` for other, the rest should be the same.

Comment: I mean if the URL is from a different site, then the review_url and the format change

Comment: @MISHA From different site than `yelp.ie`? Yes, then the rest will be different.